# Text relocation in .a lib file

Tags: android, android-ndk, arm

How to locate the text relocations in a .a static library containing asm file?
Text relocation error is occurring in android 23 and above. 
Used the scanelf options in the link https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Hardened/Textrels_Guide but there is no information being displayed.
Only when the elf is tried to execute it throws the Cannot link executable due to text relocations error.
How to point out the line in asm where the error occurs any suggestions?